# error: incompatible types: Preference cannot be converted to CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, android-source, android-preferences

I am using Preference in aosp 10 Settings. I given import statmement too but I get an error as Preference cannot be converted to CheckBoxpreference.Also in onPreferenceTree too.

```
  import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;




 public class MainActivity extends SettingsPreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceChangeListener, OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
      private CheckBoxPreference mAuthEnableBox;
public static final String KEY_PROXY_ENABLE = "checkbox_key_proxy_enable";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Read xml layout
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.proxy_settings);

      mAuthEnableBox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(KEY_PROXY_AUTH_ENABLE);

 }
@Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
        super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
       //Will implement the function but it's showing error. 

        return true;

    }
```

Error:

```
 error: incompatible types: Preference cannot be converted to CheckBoxPreference
        mProxyEnableBox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(KEY_PROXY_ENABLE);
 no suitable method found for 

    onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen,android.preference.Preference)
            super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
                 ^
        method OnPreferenceTreeClickListener.onPreferenceTreeClick(androidx.preference.Preference) is not applicable
          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
        method PreferenceFragmentCompat.onPreferenceTreeClick(androidx.preference.Preference) is not applicable
          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: It looks like your `SettingsPreferenceFragment` is using androidx preferences. Your `MainActivity` is using the platform preferences. You need to use the same in both, preferably the androidx versions.

Comment: Not exactly relevant to the current issue, but `Fragment` subclasses usually do not have `Activity` in their names. It tends to lead to confusion.

Comment: @MikeM.  Thanks for pointing out difference in use of androidx and platform preference. I also had build error for this.